# Central force law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

An object has an orbit in polar coordinates as $r(\theta) = a\theta^2$ (where $a$ is constant).

Assuming the central force is directed towards the origin $r=0$, how can I know which central force law lead to such an orbit? And how to find $r$ and $\theta$ as function of time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give away the answer directly. So I will provide some hints.

A central force in polar coordinates has to be of the form: $$\vec{F} = m\vec{a} = m(\ddot r - r \dot \theta^2)\hat r$$

Now try to mess around with your $r(\theta) = a\theta^2 $

I believe you need to specify $\dot \theta$ in order to solve the full equation of motion. So pick for your self. A linear equation $\theta = kt $ may be a good starting point.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But I don't know how to determine "central force law"; are there many "central force laws"? What are their properties? When I search google, I just found Kepler's 3 laws.....

Comment: Central force laws are a set of force laws that only have radial component. There are many different central forces that you can come up with, but all of them should be multiple of $\hat r$ the unit radial vector.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I can help.

For any object in orbit, the Earth exerts a force on the object and the object exerts a force on the Earth.

So we know from $F=ma$ that:

$$∑ F_θ=ma_θ$$

Using polar coordinates {r,θ}, this equation becomes:

$$ 0=2\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right) \implies \frac{1}{r} \left(r\left(2\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right)\right)\right) $$

$$ 0=\frac{1}{r} \left(2r\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)+r^2\left(\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}\right)\right) \implies \frac{1}{r} \left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^2\dfrac{dθ}{dt}\right)\right)=0$$

Integrating yields: $$r^2\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=h$$ where $h$ is the constant of integration

Therefore:$$\dfrac{dθ}{dt}=\dfrac{h}{r^2}$$

This proves Kepler's Second Law that the aerial velocity of a particle subjected to central-force motion is constant.

Remember that this also accounts for orbital eccentricity.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't think this is what the poster was asking...